# Looping through a folder with Cell Statistics

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, python-2.7

I have a folder with Day 1 Min, Day 1 Max and Day 2 Min, Day 2 Max...Day X Min, Day X Max rasters in it. I want to loop through this folder and use cell statistics on them to sum each day's min/max values (i.e. Day 1 Min + Day 1 Max).

I tried the following and got no results. Any pointers? How do I ensure that Cell Stats is summing the same days and not across multiple days?

```
MainFolder = r"C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\2015\RasterCon2015"
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(MainFolder):
    for dir in dirs:
        env.workspace = os.path.join(path, dir)
        listRstrs = arcpy.ListRasters("Con.tif")
        for raster in listRstrs:
            rasterlist = []
            rasterlist.append(raster)
            outCellStats = CellStatistics(rasterlist, "SUM", "DATA")
            outCellStats.save(os.path.join(path, dir) + "Check.tif")
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question and more importantly the folder structure you are looping over correctly. You need to remove your actual call to `CellStatistics` to outside the loop where you are appending your rasters in.

There are a few other issues with this code [per documentation here](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/cell-statistics.htm) the input list to `arcpy.CellStatistics` needs to be of  `Layer`, `Raster`, or `Constant` type. You were providing a list of paths to the raster. You need to convert the paths being looped over from `listRstrs` to `arcpy.Raster` and then add them to `rasterlist`. Further, you should not provide 'Con.tif' to the function `arcpy.ListRasters` this will only match rasters with that name. Once `env.workspace` is defined call `arcpy.ListRaster` and that will return all of the rasters within `env.workspace`

The corrected code should look something like this:

```
    env.workspace = os.path.join(path, dir)
    listRstrs = arcpy.ListRasters('*')
    rasterlist = []
    for path_to_raster in listRstrs:
        raster_dataset = arcpy.Raster(path_to_raster)            
        rasterlist.append(raster_dataset)
    outCellStats = CellStatistics(rasterlist, "SUM", "DATA")
    outCellStats.save(os.path.join(path, dir) + "Check.tif")
```

The way you were doing it was running `CellStatistics` each time a raster path, not `arcpy.Raster` as required, was added to `rasterlist`. So once for each raster path as well as for each raster path combination. However because you were providing the wildcard of `'Con.tif'` to `arcpy.ListRasters` only one raster path, that of `Con.tif` was being looped over. By doing it how I have shown in the snippet above you are populating your list with the relevant `arcpy.raster` objects and then running `CellStatistics` on the fully populated list.

Comment: If I change the output path to save to:           outCellStats.save(os.path.join(path, dir + "Check.tif"), at that line I get the following error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (Script3.py, line 66)
Failed to execute (Script3).

Comment: well I would go with what you have then. I ran a quick test and was receiving the error I noted. I will remove that from my answer. Hopefully you are able to get everything running with the other change I suggested :-)

Comment: The folder structure is Daily Min, Daily Max, RasterCon inside the 2015 folder. The inputs to RasterCon are reclassified rasters from Daily Min and Daily Max. Within RasterCon, I want matching days to be summed using Cell Statistics. Moving CellStatistics to outside the loop didn't work; there is still no output. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Uma please see the updated answer. I changed the format for clarity. Let me know if that works out for you.

Comment: You can simplify the code as `rasterlist = [arcpy.Raster(r) for r in arcpy.ListRasters('*')]` +1 for explanations

Comment: @GeoSharp, when you say 'define workspace' do you mean replace the first line in your example above to                                               `env.workspace = r"C:\Users\uma.bhandaram\Desktop\2015\RasterCon2015"` (where the rasters are) and then keep the rest? That gives me an error of 'path' not being defined.